# Text to the right of a section heading

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment

This is a macro that defines a heading for a project

```
   \newcommand{\project}[2]{
    %1: project name
    %2: percentage of time
    \subsection*{#1 \begin{flushright} \textcolor{darkgray}{#2\%}\end{flushright}}
    }
```

This is the command and the output:

```
\project{My Project}{25}
```

[image]

I want the percentage to be displayed in the same line as the project name. How can I format this?

Comment: Remove the `flushright` environment and use `\hfill` instead: `\newcommand{\project}[2]{\subsection*{#1\hfill\textcolor{darkgray}{#2\%}}}`. Next time please post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: @PierPaolo Wanna turn that into an asnwer and get the Q off the list of unanswered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>As @Johannes_B suggested, I turned my comment into an answer.</sup>

In order to achieve your desired look, remove the `flushright` environment and use `\hfill` instead:

```
\newcommand{\project}[2]{\subsection*{#1\hfill\textcolor{darkgray}{#2\%}}}
```

In fact, the first thing `flushright` does is to invoke `\parsep\parskip`, which basically starts a new line.

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newcommand{\project}[2]{%
  \subsection*{#1\hfill\textcolor{darkgray}{#2\%}}}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\subsection{Whatever}
\project{My Project}{25}
\lipsum[1]% dummy text, to show line width
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Note

If you were to decide you wanted `\project` to add an entry in the Table of Contents and would do so by changing `\subsection*` into `\subsection` in the definition of `\project`, the result would be ugly.

Comment: The problem with this is, that `hyperref` will complain about `Token not allowed in a PDF string (Unicode):(hyperref) removing '\hfill'`. Also, it will end up in table of contents as you hint. Is there a way around this?